# MySQL Select the column from the lowest ID

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select from the lowest ID a Column? I want to get kartikelpict, from that the lowest nNr and from the lowest nNr the cPfad.

```
tartikelpict
+--------------+--------------+-------+
| kartikelpict |     cPfad    |  nNr  |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
|     560      | picture4.jpg |   4   |
|     560      | picture3.jpg |   3   |
|     560      | picture2.jpg |   2   |
|     560      | picture.jpg  |   1   |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
|     561      | picture4.jpg |   4   |
|     561      | picture3.jpg |   3   |
|     561      | picture2.jpg |   2   |
|     561      | picture.jpg  |   1   |
+--------------+--------------+-------+

tartikel
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+
| kArtikel | cName |  cKurzBeschreibung  | dErstellt  | cSeo  |
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+
|   560    | 12345 |   Short Description | 2014-03-25 | 12345 |
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+
|   561    | ABCDE |   Short Description | 2014-03-25 | abcde |
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+
```

This is my request

```
SELECT 
    p1.kArtikel, 
    p2.kartikelpict,
    p2.nNr,
    p2.cPfad
    FROM tartikel AS p1
    JOIN tartikelpict AS p2 
    ON (p1.kArtikel = p2.kartikelpict)
    JOIN (SELECT kartikelpict, cPfad, MIN(nNr) nNr FROM tartikelpict GROUP BY kartikelpict) p3
    ON(p2.kartikelpict = p3.kartikelpict AND p2.nNr = p3.nNr AND p3.nNr = p3.cPfad)
    ORDER BY p1.kArtikel;
```

This is the PHP Code I am calling

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $nNr = $row['nNr'];
    echo "\t\t" . '<link>http://domain/'.$cSeo.'</link>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you show, what rows do you want to get in this example?

Comment: It seems you have two rows in this table which share the lowest `nNr` value.  They happen to have the same cPfad value, but not the same kartikelpict value. What should your result set look like? Please provide an example.

Comment: Example: I will get the **ID at kartikelpict** with 560, there I want to join it and find the lowest nNr with 1, if I get the lowest (1) than I want to select picture.jpg

Comment: Why do you need to include table `tartikel`?

Comment: I have been asked for that

Answer (score 0):

cPfad seems to be messing your subquery and join clauses. Try this:

```
SELECT p1.kArtikel, 
    p2.kartikelpict,
    p2.nNr,
    p2.cPfad
FROM tartikel AS p1
JOIN tartikelpict AS p2  
     ON (p1.kArtikel = p2.kartikelpict)
JOIN (SELECT kartikelpict,  MIN(nNr) min_nNr FROM tartikelpict GROUP BY kartikelpict) p3
     ON (p2.kartikelpict = p3.kartikelpict AND p2.nNr = p3.min_nNr)
ORDER BY p1.kArtikel;
```

Comment: I don't know what's he trying to get. The tartikel table wasn't mentioned in the question, but I kept his query as it was.

Comment: Somehow still not the correct output. Here is the whole Code: http://pastebin.com/BZ9eSkvT

Comment: What's the output you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM tartikelpict x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT kartikelpict
            , MIN(nNr) min_nnr
         FROM tartikelpict 
        GROUP 
           BY kartikelpict
     ) y
    ON y. kartikelpict =  x.kartikelpict
   AND y. min_nnr = x.nnr;
```

Comment: I have added your Code but still having trouble with selecting from the lowest nNr the cPath http://pastebin.com/ZGjt5GBd

Comment: What problem? I'm not really interested in the PHP (and your API is deprecated), so just provide an sqlfiddle.